# Elements which have absolute position are automatically "___" the text flow

Tags: css

I want to say "set by" but I am not confident with the answer. maybe "controlled by" I don't think it's "removed from"  or "shared with"  I tried looking for the answer by myself but i just cant figure it out and w3school inst working for some reason.

Comment: w3schools is not the only resource on the web. In fact, it is not particularly good. Try http://www.sitepoint.com/ or https://developer.mozilla.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it IS "removed from." Absolute positioning removes the element from the text flow and places it "absolutely" where you want it using properties `left` `top` `right` and `bottom`.  It will be positioned relative to it's parent element.

Hope this helps!